# How to import Files from node_modules/ folder in my view files?

Tags: javascript, php, html, npm, twig

I'm trying to learn some new technologies so I decided to give npm a try, so I download theses packages(jquery and jquery-validation) using npm and now I'm trying to link theses packages to my view file but I can`t access any outside the public folder.

Should I being using some other component that I'm not aware of or there's some way to make my packages in node_modules/ accessible?

I've tried to connect the usual away but is not happening

Heres my structure folder and a few important files:

- myproject

  - App

    - Controllers
    - Models
    - Views

      - Signup

        - **new.html**
      - **base.html**
  - Core
  - node_modules

    - jquery
    - jquery-validation
  - public

    - **index.php(Front Controller)**
  - etc...

Base.html (I'm using twig as a template engine)

```
<nav>
    <a href="/">Home</a>
</nav>

{% block body %} 
{% endblock %}

<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

index.php

```
/**
 * Front Controller
 */

 /**
  * Composer
  */
require '../vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Error and Exception handling
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler('Core\Error::errorHandler');
set_exception_handler('Core\Error::exceptionHandler');

 /**
  * Routing
  */
$router = new Core\Router();

// Add the routes
$router->add('', ['controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index']);
$router->add('{controller}/{action}');
//$router->add('{controller}/{id:\d+}/{action}');
//$router->add('admin/{controller}/{action}', ['namespace' => 'Admin']);

$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Comment: Your `base.html` file is in the views folder, while you are trying to access the node_modules folder that is one level up. In order to access that, use `../node_modules/`

Comment: I've tried that, I've tried go one level up and even two levels up not the result is the same, still can't access that file.